# Steps in deploying Android App developed using Titanium to Google Play store

Tags: titanium, google-play

I am using Titanium Studio to build my application, i have got it released in app store for iPhone.

But now i am trying to publish this to Google Play store. Below are the steps i am following, please let me know if i am doing wrong

**1) Created a Google Publisher account (to get access to Google Play console)**

**2) Build my application in Titanium Studio, and copied the `app.apk` file from `/build/android/bin` directory**

**3) Uploaded this `app.apk` file in Google play store**

I know i should add more details like appicon, screenshots to the app before publishing it.

But is this the correct procedure? because i can see in some articles suggesting 
to create private key to package app.apk file.

Please suggest.

Comment: balanv when i updated or created my app (used) Unity i had to create private and public key for the 1 to 1 link with the app. I believe same process applies for the titanium since your app will need to be signed before upload / publish to google play store.

Comment: Ok Can you suggest any reference to add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

balanv here is the link i have for signing APK for unity: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/149094/android-apk-signing.html

OR one closer to your problem:

https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Packaging+for+the+Android+Market

also look at https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Packaging+for+the+Android+Market